# How can I elegantly apply a projection to an entire MongoDB collection using Cashbah

Tags: mongodb, casbah

Assuming that `coll` is a [MongoCollection](http://mongodb.github.io/casbah/api/#com.mongodb.casbah.MongoCollection), I know that I can select all documents by calling `coll.find()`, and I know that I can apply a projection to all documents by calling `coll.find("_id" $exists true, projection)` where `projection` might be something like `MongoDBObject("_id" -> 1)`. Is there a way to do this more elegantly, like (just imagined) `coll.find($everything, projection)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An empty document will perform a find all eg:

```
coll.find(MongoDBObject(), projection)
```